# Revert a reject/approval of a change in Documentation

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, documentation

I've accidentally approved a change in Documentation that resulted in the removal of the entire Topic. This was not the intent of my action and I would like to revert it, is it possible?

Comment: I just had the same derp... I feel bad now.

Comment: Same here. Especially in documentation, there should either be a required two count vote for approvals like there is for rejects, or there needs to be rollbacks on a vote.

Comment: I also did something similar. I approved a new example that was only 2 lines long and was rejected by another user, because I thought it was a proposed edit to an existing example (I hadn't actually seen what a proposed edit looked like at that point).

Comment: For my first approval, I accidentally approved something that was erroneous because I misunderstood something on the page.  I understood once I saw another user's rejection and comment.

Comment: I just said someone plagiarized an example when he was just adding a line at the bottom.  Now I have to delete my account.  SON OF A BITCH.

Comment: Same here, rejected and then changed my mind.. :(